# Deepchem: Multiple (multi-molecule) input regression

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, deep-learning

With Deepchem regression, how is the multi-molecule regression.

I read [this](https://github.com/pchanda/Graph_Convolutions_with_Molecules/blob/master/GraphConv_tr_te.py).

It's a regression for one molecule (smiles),

**dataset**

```
cLogP,cLogS,Smiles
3.3344,-4.043,COc(c1ccccc11)ccc1S(NCCOc1ccccc1)(=O)=O
0.5955,-2.606,CCOc(ccc(S(N)(=O)=O)c1)c1C#N
```

However, I want the regression for two or more molecules.

**dataset**

```
X-parameter,Y-parameter,Smiles-1, Smiles-2
2.3344,9.043,COc(c1ccccc11)ccc1S(NCCOc1ccccc1)(=O)=O, CCO
1.5955,3.606,CCOc(ccc(S(N)(=O)=O)c1)c1C#N, CN=C=O
```

I should change the codes below and others.

```py
def data_generator(dataset, epochs=1, predict=False, pad_batches=True):
  for epoch in range(epochs):
    if not predict:
        print('Starting epoch %i' % epoch)
    data_iterator_batch = dataset.iterbatches(batch_size, pad_batches=pad_batches, deterministic=True)
    for ind, (X_b, y_b, w_b, ids_b) in enumerate(data_iterator_batch):
      d = {} #sort of feed_dict
      for index, label in enumerate(labels):
        d[label] = np.expand_dims(y_b[:, index],1)
      d[weights] = w_b
      multiConvMol = ConvMol.agglomerate_mols(X_b)
      d[atom_features] = multiConvMol.get_atom_features()
      d[degree_slice] = multiConvMol.deg_slice
      d[membership] = multiConvMol.membership
      for i in range(1, len(multiConvMol.get_deg_adjacency_lists())):
        d[deg_adjs[i - 1]] = multiConvMol.get_deg_adjacency_lists()[i]
      yield d
```

I have no idea how to change the codes